# How to make hover effects on jump link blogger function?

Tags: css, blogger

Good day to you:)
Firstly I added a css hover effect on jump-link function on blogger, but it hadn't work

Here is my css :

```
.jump-link a {
    -webkit-transition: color 0.3s;
    -moz-transition: color 0.3s;
    transition: color 0.3s;
}

.jump-link a::before {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 50%;
    color: transparent;
    content: '\2022';
    text-shadow: 0 0 transparent;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    -webkit-transition: text-shadow 0.3s, color 0.3s;
    -moz-transition: text-shadow 0.3s, color 0.3s;
    transition: text-shadow 0.3s, color 0.3s;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
    -moz-transform: translateX(-50%);
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    pointer-events: none;
}

.jump-link a:hover::before,
.jump-link a:focus::before {
    color: #fff;
    text-shadow: 10px 0 #fff, -10px 0 #fff;
}

.jump-link a:hover,
.jump-link a:focus {
    color: #ba7700;
}
```

I will be thankful for any help . :)

Answer (score 0):

```
.jump-link a:hover{color:red;text-decoration:underline;}
```

Also don't use two `::` in `.jump-link a:hover::before`

For example code below will add a "+" when user hovers any link.

```
 a:hover:before {
    content: "+";
    }
```